# Does a leaf mean a "leaf" or a "sheet"?

Tags: meaning

A **leaf** from her diary is included in the book but not in the exhibition.

My question is:

Does a **leaf** mean a **leaf** or a **sheet**?

Comment: Did you look up 'leaf' in a dictionary?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think he did, but both meanings are true for the word "leaf". Maybe he couldn't guess the meaning related with the context.

Comment: In general, leaves from trees are not included in books.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Must be a few in Ali Smith's *Autumn*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context it almost certainly means "a single piece of paper"

If you happen to know that she was in the habit of keeping leaves from trees and plants in her diary then I suppose it could mean a tree leaf.  How many people do you know that keep tree leaves in their diaries?